# Is there a way to update the field inside the each Document of a collectionGroup in cloud function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am making my first angular/Firestore app and I am having some trouble understanding how to update the field or make the new field in collectionsGroup. The Firestore dB path I want to read from is here `Order(CollectionGroupName)/7WqHl5YUKPszkRELXEI2(auto-id)`

So **Order** collectionGroup Name and 7WqHl5YUKPszkRELXEI2 is an auto-id for an added order.
I want to **ADD** and **UPDATE** the field name **Status** whenever I want to click the button.

This is my button code where I am passing **auto-id(Document-Id)** and String value

```
 <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="updates(element.id,'Inprocess')">Status</button>
```

This is my update field code

```
updates(id: string, _value: string) {let doc = this.firestore.collectionGroup<Item>('Order', ref => ref.where('id', '==', id));doc.get().subscribe((snapshot)=>{
 snapshot.forEach(doc=>{
  this.firestore.collection('Order').doc(id).update({Status: _value});
  console.log('successful')
 }) })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a document reference to the document you want to update.

```
const cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Set the 'capital' field of the city
const res = await cityRef.update({capital: true});
```

Please check more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

And when you want to update it in multiple documents do this, you might need bulk writer.

```
let bulkWriter = firestore.bulkWriter();
let documentRef = firestore.doc('col/doc');

bulkWriter
 .update(documentRef, {foo: 'bar'})
 .then(result => {
   console.log('Successfully executed write at: ', result);
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.log('Write failed with: ', err);
 });
});
```

Check [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/BulkWriter.html#update) for more details.